# Selecting a form by name within a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, forms, dom, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to access a form by its name from the content scripts

```
document.querySelector("form[name=myForm]") //works fine
document.myForm //returns undefined
```

What is the reason I can't get a form by its name from an extension?

```
document.myForm //in the browser console, works as expected
```

Comment: I'm assuming you are in fact using this code within an extension and have updated the tags accordingly. Rollback the changes if not.

Comment: It's a bug in the browser. It doesn't propagate html_document->DocumentNamedItems into the isolated world of content scripts. The workaround is to use the deprecated document.all.myForm